# The probability of $x>0.25$

Tags: probability

> Consider $ax+b=0$ equation. The $a$ and $b$ are coefficients which $a$ has been randomly chosen from $[1,2]$ and $b$ has been chosen from $[-1,1]$. Determine the probability of $x> 0.25$.

My try: I tried to graph $ax+b$ with $a \in [1 , 2]$ and $b \in [-1 , 1]$ conditions but I don't know how it is possible .

Note : I saw problems like this and I know those can be solved using graphs and ratio of areas , lengths or volumes but I am interested in a method without needs to drawing graphs.

Comment: You _will_ have to draw a graph for this one.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Are you sure ?

Comment: @downvote Can you explain why ?!

Comment: Must have been the man on the Clapham omnibus. I didn't downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote either.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thank you . Can you draw the graph for this problem ?

Comment: @drhab Okay , Thank you too .

Comment: With a graph: Find the area of $\{\langle a,b\rangle\in[1,2]\times[-1,1]\mid \frac14a+b<0\}$ (and divide by the area of $[1,2]\times[-1,1])$. Preassumed that $a$ and $b$ are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the boundary case $a\cdot\frac14+b=0$ or $b=-\frac14a$. Now draw a rectangle:
[image]
The shaded area is where the solution for $x$ is greater than 0.25; it is a trapezium with area $\frac{(2-1)(3/4+1/2)}2=\frac58$. The whole sample space has area 2, so the final probability is
$$\frac{5/8}2=\frac5{16}$$

Comment: Okay , Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb P(x>0.25)=P(ax+b>0.25a+b)=P(0.25a+b<0)$. To find this probability use joint distribution of a and b.

[EDITED]

Assuming $a$ and $b$ to be independent
$P(0.25a+b<0)=P(a<-4b)=\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{1}^{min(-4b,2)}dadb$

Comment: Can you continue please ?

Comment: @S.H.W Have you allready tried yourself then? You are asking $5$ minutes after publication.

Comment: @drhab I'm sorry but I am not familiar with distribution .

Answer (score 1):

$x=\frac{-b}{a}$. $a$ cannot be negative. So for $x>0.25$, $b$ has to be less than $0$. And given $b$, $a>-4b$. But $a\leq2$, so $b>-1/2$. Assuming $a$ and $b$ to be independent, $$P(x>0.25)=\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^0\int_{-4b}^2dadb$$